# Pass login data from excel file using selenium java. not able to use getRow() , getCell()

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I want to pass username and password in a webpage from excel sheet. help me to get the out put.
error is display as red underline in getRow(), getColumn(), getCell() etc.

This is my java file:

```
public class NewTest_tstng_excel {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public static   XSSFSheet excelSheet;
  public void login() {
      driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();



  }
  @BeforeClass
    public void testSetup() {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    }
  @Test(dataProvider="empLogin")
    public void VerifyInvalidLogin(String userName, String password) {

      driver.get("URL goes here");
      driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(userName);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(password);
      driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).submit();


  }

  @DataProvider(name="empLogin")
    public Object[][] loginData() {
        Object[][] arrayObject = getExcelData("E:\\disha.shah\\myWork\\sele_proj\\FAM_Excel data\\src\\DataFile\\Book1.xlsx","Sheet1");
        return arrayObject;
    }


  public String[][] getExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName) {

      String[][] arrayExcelData = null;



      try {
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
            //Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
            //Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
            excelSheet = workBook.getSheet("Sheet1");
            int totalNoOfCols = excelSheet.getColumns();

            int totalNoOfRows = excelSheet.getRows();

            arrayExcelData = new String[totalNoOfRows-1][totalNoOfCols];

            for (int i= 1 ; i < totalNoOfRows; i++) {

                for (int j=0; j < totalNoOfCols; j++) {
                    arrayExcelData[i-1][j] = excelSheet.getCell(j, i).getContents();

                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arrayExcelData;
    }

    @Test
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();

        }

  }
```

in excel: there is 2 column containing username and password.

Answer (score 0):

See if getRow is null.
You can do createRow().
If in the excel you don't use the row you need, you will have to create a new row, otherwise you use getRow if the row is already in use!

Comment: there is data available in the row

Comment: What you are trying to do in this line: int totalNoOfRows = excelSheet.getRows();

Comment: trying to get number of rows in sheet. but the red line error is display under getRows()

Comment: if you want to get the number of Rows, use: getLastRowNum(), I think is like this, and with this method you get the last row. And it will give you the last row in use, and with that you do a cicle to get the content of the rows.